# Django models.Textfield automatically wrapped in <p></p> in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a the following class defined in `models.py`:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
```

In my template I render it with `{{ entry.content|linebreaks }}`. The output is automatically wrapped in `<p>Output of entry.content</p>` tags. Yet I would like to give the paragraph a certain class `<p class="my-class">Output of entry.content</p>`. How can I specify that in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The tag is hard coded into the filter.

Wrap it with another element `<div class="my-class">` to use your selector or see if `linebreaksbr` is an appropriate filter to use within your own paragraph class (depends how long the content is / how you style your paragraphs).

Comment: Thanks! `linebreaksbr` is exactly what I was looking for.